# Swift Core Data Quirk

Tags: swift, core-data

Can anyone help me figure out why this code is behaving thusly...

When opening the app for the first time a "User" is created (if it doesn't already exist, which it doesn't the first time) and then the user is saved along with his/her golf "clubs". I get confirmation of the user saved and the clubs saved in the console. HOWEVER, when I close the app and reopen it the user is fetched but the clubs are not. What am I missing here? Let me know if you need/want to see any screen captures beyond this code...

```
//MARK: Core Data Variables
var user : User!
var userClubs = NSMutableSet()
var currentRound : Round!
var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

func prepareUser() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdTime", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let fetchResults = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [User] {
        if fetchResults.count > 0 {
            self.user = fetchResults[0]
            println("First user: \(self.user!.firstName) \(self.user!.lastName)")

            let fetchRequestClubs = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Club")
            if let fetchResults2 = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestClubs, error: nil) as? [Club] {
                if fetchResults2.count > 0 {
                    println("test: \(fetchResults2[0].type)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("No user yet")
            var newUser : User = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! User

            newUser.createdTime = NSDate()

            managedObjectContext.save(nil)

            var i = 0
            println("before array: clubsArray is \(clubsArray.count) clubs long")
            var clubs = NSMutableSet.mutableSetValueForKey("clubs")

            for newClub in clubsArray {
                var club : Club = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Club", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Club
                club.type = clubsArray[i].type as String
                club.estimatedMinYardage = clubsArray[i].minDistance as Int
                club.estimatedMaxYardage = clubsArray[i].maxDistance as Int
                club.lowerBound = clubsArray[i].lowerBound as Int
                club.upperBound = clubsArray[i].upperBound as Int
                //userClubs.addObject(club)
                managedObjectContext.save(nil)

                //club.setValue(newUser, forKey: "user")
                println("\(club.type)")
                i++
            }

            //user.setValue(userClubs, forKey: "clubs")
            prepareUser()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the console output from the first run:

- No user yet
- before array: clubsArray is 17 clubs long
- Putter
- LW
- SW
- PW
- 9i
- 8i
- 7i
- 6i
- 5i
- 5W 
  ... [the rest of the clubs]
- First user: Your Name
- test: 7i

And from the second run after closing and reopening the app:

- First user: Your Name

Comment: Is the `Club` class included in the app target and configured as the class for the `Club` entity? I'm wondering if the `as?` on the fetch is failing.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm newish to Core Data/Swift and your comment prompted me to create other instances of other classes and it turns out they were saved properly. Now I have to figure out how to see if the Club class is included in the app target and then figure out how to change the setting if it is not. I created the Club class in the .xcdatamodeld after the other classes so I must've overlooked something.

Comment: Crap I checked and Club class is included in the app target and is configured as the class for the data model entity.

Comment: Sorry another thought/question: I created a class called Club before I implemented Core Data. Having forgot that I had a class by the same name I compiled the code (don't remember what error/warning message I got but I think i got something). I simply commented out the previous implementation of the Club class and let xcode generate a new Club class for me based off of the data model. Might there be residual conflict? If so how do I correct?

Comment: K, I'm pretty sure it has everything to do with my for loop. I just tried to create and save one instance of the Club class without the looping and it persisted. I'm doing something wrong methinks with the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bloody hell. I was trying to set 1 of the 17 instances of the Club class to a value that was less than it's minimum value allowed in the data model. If anyone else is having a similar issue check your min/max and default in addition to what @Tom-Harrington suggested in the comments of the original question. Dunno if Apple could get some kind of warning for this kind of thing into future versions of XCode.

Comment: They do provide a check-- when you save changes, the result is a boolean value that returns `false` on failure. If that happens, the argument to `save` will describe the reason. You need to check, though. :)

Comment: Gracias, sir! Showing my familiarity with swift and core data. Thanks for taking the time to help.